# In Java, why should we specify the exception type in the catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have been coding in Java for work but everything I know about Java comes from googling how to do anything whenever I need to know. I have done C/C++ at school before and now I'm just getting into exception handling in Java.

In Java, why should we specify the exception type in the catch block? What are some advantages to doing so? What are some disadvantages to just using Exception instead of, say "IOException"?

Also when should I use the try/catch block when coding? I noticed that I got into the pattern of just coding the logic part, and I only add try/catch if an error shows while coding telling me to add it, or when I run the code and the program quits halfway because of an exception, then I find where it happens in the code and add the try/catch block there to "handle the exception" in order to get the code keep running. Is this how people normally decide where to add in try/catch? Is there a more efficient way such as "when doing certain things in code, add try/catch"?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
When should I use try/catch blocks and when should I use `private void method() throws Exception`? What's the difference between the two besides the syntax?

Comment: Start at the [beginning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). **Don't take shortcuts.**

Comment: "You want exception handlers to be as specific as possible. The reason is that the first thing a handler must do is determine what type of exception occurred before it can decide on the best recovery strategy"

Comment: Note that for some situations (catch-all "an error has ocurred!" messages), using just an `Exception` is fine.

Comment: You put "handle the exception" in scare quotes, why?  If you want your program to keep on running after an exception happens then you have to _handle_ the exception... Even if that just means writing a message to a log, and moving on to the next item is a list, that's still _handling_ it.

Comment: I guess I'm just still in the C/C++ mode where I used to code everything into if/else and use try/catch is just to get the code to not stop half way.. :)

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ programmer, but that certainly doesn't sound like good C/C++ code... Try/catch blocks shouldn't be used just to "make the program work". Good design and fixing the *root* of the problem is preferable to just patching things over by catching the exception and moving on.

Comment: there is no try/catch in C/C++, and everything has to be done with if/else to avoid errors if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2):

A lot of relatively new programmers have this thought that all exceptions are bad, but this isn't true. Exceptions are neither good or bad. They just provide information.

Take `NullPointerExceptions` vs `FileNotFoundExceptions`.

Generally (not always), if a `NullPointerException` is thrown, it means that there was a bug in your code somewhere. You forgot to initialize a variable, didnt check to see if a flag was true, etc. When these exceptions are thrown, you generally want your program to fail and crash, because it encountered unexpected behavior. You want the failure to be loud and obvious, because if the program didn't fail immediately after a null pointer, the program might get really wacky, and you would have a hard time finding the problem.

However, `FileNotFoundExceptions` are generally the opposite.

Imagine if at some point in your program, you prompted the user for a file. The user may or may not input a valid file, but the program shouldn't crash here either way. Instead, the user should be notified if the file can't be found, and prompted again. This is generally why you have catch blocks, so if that exception gets thrown, you can handle it and continue (by displaying your dialog/message/whatever).

However, if a `NullPointerException` was thrown here, you would definetly want your program to crash (as it's probably a bug in your code). This is why catch blocks force you to specify the Exception, so you can deal with some (such as `FileNotFoundException`), and let others through (such as `NullPointerException`)

Generally, you want to catch exceptions if your program is capable of recovering from that exception. This is (supposed to be) why java forces you to `try/catch` certain exceptions. Most of those exceptions are meant to be exceptions your program should be able to recover from (although sometimes, you would want to fail instead, either by declaring that your method throws that exception, or wrapping the caught exception in a `RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 0):

I might be leaving out details I am unfamiliar with myself. But as far as I know specifying the specific exception type, allows you to get more detailed info on the error in the log.

Also eclipse and other ide's usually show a warning when it's "proper" to use try/catch blocks.

Hope it answers the question to some extent

Comment: You could always cast the exception inside the catch block. The point of catching an exception is when you know how to handle it. If you catch everything of type exception... well you catch and potentially improperly dispose of new problems.

Comment: True. I guess you could use specific types for finding details about the error if you need to and change it back to the general exception type when your done with fixing errors fx.

Comment: Why would you turn it back into the general exception type. It already fits that object type if it is an exception. The point of a `try catch` is to insulate your code from any known potential failures. Not to blithely catch everything and then dispose of them like they are all equal. When I see code that catches `exception` and not a concrete type I immediately question whether that code could have unintended consequences. (outside of the final app try catch to protect itself from crashing obviously)

Comment: So first you think it's a good idea to catch general exceptions to prvent future problems and now your argumenting the opposite? Having a little debate with yourself?

Comment: No, I think it is a good idea to catch exceptions you expect. That being said, letting your application crash due to an exception is not good.

Answer (score 0):

The point of specifying which exceptions to catch is fairly straight forward.  The main thing to remember is that Exceptions are classes, and have an inheritence hierarchy.   For example, IOException inherits from Exception.  This allows you to catch different exceptions, and handle them in different ways.

```
try {
 ....
} catch (IOException e){
    logger.fatal("An IO Exception occurred.");
} catch (NullPointerException e){
    logger.info("A null pointer exception occurred.");
}
```

In the above example, an IO exception will be logged as fatal, but a null pointer is only logged at the info level.  Any exceptions that may be thrown besides these two will not be caught, and will be thrown to the next level of error handling.  This could either crash your program, or a method higher up the call chain may handle the thrown exception.

```
try {
 ....
} catch (IOException e){
    logger.fatal("An IO Exception occurred.");
} catch (NullPointerException e){
    logger.info("A null pointer exception occurred.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.fatal("An unexpected exception occurred.");
}
```

In this second example, all exceptions are caught.  Only one catch block will be executed though (The first one that matches).

A good way to plan when writing code is to:
1) Determine if this line of code can fail.  (IO, parsing text, calling a service...).
2) If this code fails, do I want to handle this failure here (with a catch block) or later, by throwing the exception up the call chain.